# Warnings encountered loading management data

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

When accessing the Azure Portal, I get the following error:

```
Warnings encountered loading management data.
```

If I click show details it shows:

```
There was an error when we tried to load namespaces in subscription ID
'id here'
```

If I try to use powershell to create a new ServiceBus I get the following error

```
PS C:\> New-AzureSBNamespace -Name testsbsf -Location "West Europe" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging

New-AzureSBNamespace : <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Request to a downlevel
service failed.</string>
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureSBNamespace -Name testsbsf -Location "West Europe" -CreateACSNamespac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just started working again, I'm guessing some random downtime.

Answer (score 0):

I received "Request to a downlevel service failed" in PowerShell when the namespace already exists.